# glassfish 5.0 not start

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish

This is my code

```
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class EchoServer {

    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String incomingMessage) {
        return "I got this (" + incomingMessage + ")"
                + " so I am sending it back !";
    }        
}
```

but it throws this error, I don't know which XML is incorrect.

> Exception during lifecycle processing
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: 
>       http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html; lineNumber: 7; 
>       columnNumber: 41; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/application.xml in 
>       archive [MXONE_ear_exploded].  s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters 
>       are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 
>       'xs:documentation'. Saw 'var _U = "undefined";
>       var g_HttpRelativeWebRoot = "/ocom/";'.

How to solve it?

Comment: `I don't know which XML is incorrect.` well, the error tells you that: `Deployment descriptor file META-INF/application.xml in archive [MXONE_ear_exploded]`. Whats the `application.xml` file content?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd"
             version="8">

    </application>         i can't find where is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have older schema namespace for `application.xml`

All new schemas are at `http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/`. Most older schemas remain in the `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/` namespace.

Make sure you use newer one.

Comment: This solved it for me. I got the same error after generating an ee app using intellij 2018.5 and deploying it to Glassfish 5.0. After change to `xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee` the app is working.